# "who uses sharepoint" web site

Tags: branding, site

Sometime ago, I have come across with a silverlight site where many companies that uses sharepoint are grouped by their sector. there were screenshots of the websites designed in sharepoint. It was very cool site for getting some ideas about branding by sectors. now I am not able to find that web site(I should have bookmarked it!)
has anyone seen this site before, if so could share the link please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for WSSDemo, http://www.wssdemo.com/livepivot/.

Comment: Pretty awesome site. But the screendumps seem so blurry. Or is it just my browser?

Comment: they start a little blurry in IE9, then crisp up a bit after a few seconds

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're talking about one of these 2?

1. [Top 20 Examples of Creative Navigation with SharePoint](http://www.pinkpetrol.com/blog/2010/06/top-20-examples-of-creative-navigation-within-sharepoint/)
2. [Top SharePoint](http://www.topsharepoint.com/)